# justifyContent: 'space-evenly' in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flexbox

Can I use the `justifyContent: 'space-evenly'` on any elements in React Native? On which ones? What should the syntax look like?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be interesting if you would have posted some of the elements yourself (if applied) after reading official documentation.

Comment: I read the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html), but I couldn't find anything about 'space-evenly'. I was wondering if this was an oversight or if this element was not implemented on purpose.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned by @Ben, you can use `justifyContent: 'space-evenly'` since RN 0.54.0+.

for second part of your question i.e. "on which ones?"

> Justify Content
> Adding justifyContent to a component's style determines the distribution of children along the primary axis. Should children be distributed at the start, the center, the end, or spaced evenly? Available options are flex-start, center, flex-end, space-around, and space-between. [link to docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#justify-content)

So, logically it should be used to **container views** or **elements** to layout it's children along the primary axis.

for the third part of the question "What should the syntax look like?"

syntax is simple and you can use it like

`<View style={{justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}>children views...</View>`

for further details about `justifyContent` you can visit [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true.`space-evenly` doesn't work yet.  See this Snack. https://snack.expo.io/S1VGnZwOf

Comment: sorry for being too late. @GollyJer you were right. As mentioned below by @Ben Kane  `space-evenly` was introduced in documentation of `RN 0.52.0` and is now implemented in `RN 0.54.0`.

Comment: @GollyJer expo is yet using `RN 0.52`

Answer (score 7):

`justifyContent: 'space-evenly'` is available in React Native 0.54.0+. You can use the feature as you would any other `justifyContent` value. For example:

```js
<View style={styles.spaceEvenlyContainer}>
  {children}
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  spaceEvenlyContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly'
  }
});
```

For details, see the following:

- [0.52.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.52.0) that introduce the feature (mistakenly - it was not fully implemented yet)
- [Commit 1050e0b](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/1050e0b) that partially implements the feature
- [Pull Request #17805](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/17805) that finishes the feature implementation
- [0.54.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.54.0) that release the feature

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true.`space-evenly` doesn't work.  See this Snack. https://snack.expo.io/S1VGnZwOf

Comment: I’m guessing Snack currently uses a version of RN older than 0.52.0? I haven’t tried this in simulator yet, but I’ll verify that it works later

Comment: It is on v52.  But, I discovered the feature isn't actually implemented but will be in the next React Native release. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/17805

Comment: Thanks to @GollyJer's link, updated to show this is available in 0.54+